# How can I reuse "services" code in multiple GitHub CI jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to DRY up my GitHub `ci.yml` file somewhat. I have two jobs—one runs RSpec tests, the other runs Cucumber tests. There were a number of steps they shared, which I’ve extracted to an external action.

They both depend on a `postgres` and `chrome` Docker image however,  and some environment variables, so currently both jobs include the below code. Is there any way I can put this code in one place for them both to use? Note I’m not attempting to share the image itself, I just don’t want to have the repeated code.

```
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:13
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        # tmpfs for faster DB in RAM
        options: >-
          --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/var/lib/postgresql/data
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

      chrome:
        image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium:4.1.2-20220227
        ports:
          - 4444:4444
        env:
          DB_HOST: localhost
          CHROMEDRIVER_HOST: localhost
          RAILS_ENV: test
```

Comment: Is the yaml you showed above inside a docker-compose.yml, or is this something else?  Reason I ask is if it's docker-compose.yml, doesn't that DRY your ci.yml?  Is it possible to show the structure of the two jobs to get a more clear picture?